# The opposite word of "to meet up with someone."

Tags: word-choice

What is the opposite word of the word "**to meet (up)**" in the sense in the example sentence below.

> We met up, as we arranged, at 2 pm at the cafe and after about one
>   hour-long chat  ....... near the central metro station.

I think we can use the word "to split (up)" but it sounds to me it can be used more like when somebody breaks up with her girlfriend/boyfriend.

Thank you

Comment: In American English, _we parted near the central metro station._

Comment: You can also use  _split up_ if context makes it very clear that you are not talking about a break-up.

Comment: @Adam Thank you for your answer.Can we use the verb " to part " for friends like from college or work who probably we see again them some time maybe tomorrow. I mean it does not imply we will not see each other for long time, do it?

Comment: @Murat Yes, you can.  "We met up, as arranged, at 2PM at the cafe, and after an hour-long chat we parted near the central metro station."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the *safe* verbs is 'parted'. And after meeting with friends, 'parted' is the commonly used verb I have observed.

WordWebOnline typically addresses your concern with a similar concept.

> [parted](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/PARTED) - *Go one's own way; move apart*

The example follows: `"The friends parted after the party"`

Answer (score 1):

The verb "leave" also means to go away from a person or a place (0LD).

I think this is more common and appropriate verb that can be used here.  Alternatively, as mentioned by Maulik, we can use "part". ".........after about an hour-long chat left near the Central Metro Station".

Comment: colloquially, *leave* means break up as well. *Do you know John left Maria and she was crying a lot!* Just to add! :)

Comment: @Maulik, it's one of the meanings of leave, used as a transitive verb, whereas I am using it as an intransitive verb. Part also conveys the same meaning as you have mentioned here, when used intransitively. The couple parted amicably.

Comment: Maulik, I want to say that leave is used in different senses and part is also used in different senses. I don't disagree to your comment.